# How to convert a string to Date and then add it to excel using jexcel api

Tags: java, jexcelapi

I am currently reading a CSV file. I have to extract the dates from it and add them to excel file in `dd-MM-yy` format. I am faced with two problems.

1. I am using `String.split(delim)` where, `delim="[,]"`. I am getting the date in `yyyy-MM-dd` format.
2. I am not able to convert the string into a date format and then add them to excel file. I tried using `DateFormat` but error says `Dateformat is abstract`.

Here is the code

```
dtformat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
datenow=dtformat.parse(stringDate);//datenow is what i want to add to add.
datecell=new DateTime(tokenNumber, lineNumber, datenow);
sheet.addCell(datecell);
```

When I open the excel file, I get wild values.

Please help.Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "wild values"?  Could it be that you just need to tell Excel your date format?

Comment: I mean like the date is coming 7/3/39.

Comment: and i am getting consecutive dates as '7/3/30','7/2/28' and '7/2/35' even  etc. doesnt make any sense to me. Maybe it is not taking the date only, it is adding the time too.

Comment: When i write System.out.print(datenow), i get values like:      Sun Jul 03 00:02:00 IST 2033. Why am i getting such year and time values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is your friend.

To parse date:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse("2011 02 07");
```

To write date:

```
DateFormat customDateFormat = new DateFormat ("dd-MM-yy"); 
WritableCellFormat dateFormat = new WritableCellFormat (customDateFormat); 
sheet.addCell(new DateTime(/* date */, dateFormat));
```

Comment: I am getting this Error: java.text.DateFormat is abstract;cannot be instantiated. Where i am doing it wrong

Comment: Thanks margus; I got it. I didnt need DateFormat at all .